# How do I force an async web service call to act as synchronous?

Tags: c#, silverlight, asmx

The issue I'm having is with some asmx web services that have been ported over to a silverlight application. The problem is that asmx services on silverlight only allow for asynchronous method calls. For the most part this is acceptable, but there's one instance where I really don't want it.

At the start of every block of web calls, there's a call to a global function CheckTimeout. What this does is call a web method to see if the user's login token has expired, and if it has, to say the user has timed out and to please log back in. The problem is that I want CheckTimeout to completely finish before returning so that the calling method knows that you're still logged in before doing its various things.

I tried using an EventWaitHandler within CheckTimeout, which the method receiving the async results from the server would signal, but I guess there's really only one thread working here because the request is never even made to the web server if I do it that way. Any thoughts on how I can do what I'm looking to do?

```
private static EventWaitHandle wait_for_check_login = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    private static bool check_timeout_result = false;

    public static void CheckTimeout()
    {
        rji_ws.CheckLoginAsync(login_key);

        wait_for_check_login.WaitOne();

        if (check_timeout_result)
            {
                check_timeout_result = false;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You've timed out after a period of inactivity. Please log in again");
                login_key = Guid.Empty;
                System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.Submit();
            }


    }

    private static void CheckTimeoutResults(object sender, RJI_WS.CheckLoginCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("There was an error communicating with the server
            wait_for_check_login.Set();
        }
        else
        {
            check_timeout_result = e.Result;
            wait_for_check_login.Set();


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the call isn't making it to the server, the problem may be that you missed something in the CheckLoginAsync code (you didn't post it).

In any case, writing code this way will block the main UI thread. You are better off arranging your code in the following manner:

```
/// Usage:
///   CheckLoginThen((bool result) => { CallWebServices(); });
void CheckLoginThen(Action<bool> a) 
{
  rji_ws.CheckLoginAsync(login_key,
    (sender, e) => 
    {
      if (e.Error != null)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error communicating with the server");
      }
      else
      {
        var result = e.Result;
        a(result);
      }
    }, 
    null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code into a separate method (if it's not in one already) and call that from the handler for the checklogin service completing.